# Is there any way to open App when user click any button on Status bar Icon In Mac Desktop App

Tags: xcode, macos

Is there any way to open my App when user click Open App button on Status bar Icon In Mac Desktop App?

```
 NSStatusBar *systemStatusBar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];
    _statusItem = [systemStatusBar statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    [_statusItem setHighlightMode:NO];
    [_statusItem setMenu:self.statusMenu];
    [_statusItem setTarget:self];

    NSMenu *menu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];
    [menu addItemWithTitle:@"Open App" action:@selector(OpenAPp:) keyEquivalent:@""];
    [menu addItem:[NSMenuItem separatorItem]]; // A thin grey line
    [menu addItemWithTitle:@"Quit" action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@""];
    _statusItem.menu = menu;





-(IBAction)OpenAPp:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"here");
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
}
```

i want to lunch app when user click OpenApp button even if app is closed or even App is running in background thanks

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

With the Above line i only able to make Application Window Active

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If the app is showing its status bar menu item, then it's running. So, it doesn't need to be launched. Activating it seems like what you want, but you say it's not enough. What else do you want it to do? How is making the application and its window active different from what you want?

Comment: I just want whenever user click app icon present in Status Bar Application window Should appears on screen right now it is not working .

Comment: You need to add code to show the window (if it's not already showing). If you have a variable holding a reference to a window controller, invoke `[windowController showWindow:self]`, for example. Alternatively, if you have a variable holding a reference to the window itself, you could use `[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self]`.

Comment: sorry but i am new to OSX development so i have no idea what you are talking about can you explain it with code please just a humble request

Comment: I recommend this article: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-04-05-windows-and-window-controllers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve my problem by adding these line

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
[_window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```